# Powerbuilder - Updating A Window Control Obejct From Called Function

Tags: powerbuilder

[Calling the function with the window w_test_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWYE9.jpg)

[The code for the function wf_access_test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqDGN.jpg)

Hi

This is a simple example to hopefully explain my problem for a more complex application.

However, I am calling this function from many different windows.  So I thought rather than 'hard code' the specific window intoduce a variable.

Unfortnately as you can see from this image powerbuilder does not like it!

I am obviously doing something wrong, but I have exhausted all avenues that I am aware of.

I'm relatively new to using Powerbuilder and the manuals don't seem to have an example of this - which does seem strange to me.

An idiot guide answer would be most appreciated.

Many thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, try this:

```
Long i
StaticText  lo_st

For i = 1 to UpperBound( iw_Window.Control[] )
    If Typeof( iw_Window.Control[i] ) = statictext! Then

        lo_st = iw_Window.Control[i]
        lo_st.text = iw_Window.ClassName()

    End If

Next

Return 0
```

Comment: Hi Eduardo, yes thank you that does work!  Unfortunately, I think that by trying to give a simple example I might have inadvertantly dodge my original issue.  Addressing / Updating window instance variables from the function.  I have created an instance variabe in w_test_1  string is_text1              w_test_1.is_text1 = "This Works"   However iw_window.is_text1 = "Some other text"   does not!  This is what my brain is not allowing me to understand.  I hope this is clear?  (Sorry!)

Comment: The windowobject class doesn't have a text property. You need to
check the classname of the object and then recast the pointer to an
appropriate subclass that does have that property.

Comment: Although I agree in principle why does it work when the window name is hard coded in the function, but when iw_window (variable) is used it does not?

Comment: Because the base class of window (from which iw_window is inherited I assume) does not contain a static text control.

Comment: Matt - It could be that this question is a tad ambigious.  Thus, please see my latest question "Accessing Powerbuilder Window Instance Variables from General Function".  I'm hoping this will explain my problem more clearly?  Fingers crossed.  Many thanks anyway!